# ajax на yii2 если чпу включен

Tags: php, ajax, yii2, post

Обработчик у меня находится на мой.сайт/post/signup.php делаю запрос:

```
$("#regis").click(function(){
    var name = $(".namereg").val();
    var email = $(".emailreg").val();
    var pass = $(".passreg").val();
        if(name == '' || pass == '' || email == ''){
        alert("Поля пустые!!!");
        }else{
            $.ajax({
                url: "/post/signup.php",
                type: "POST",
                data:{name: name,pass: pass,email: email},
                success: function(data){
                $("#result").html(data);
            } 
            });
        }
});
```

но у меня почему то ответ 404 почему?

Comment: Добавьте к вопросу содержимое файла `.htaccess`

Comment: /web/: RewriteEngine On RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . index.php

Comment: корень: Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(web)
RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ /web/assets/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ web/css/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$ web/js/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ web/images/$1 [L]
RewriteRule (.*) /web/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /web/index.php

Comment: ну так если чпу включён то зачем на конце `.php` ? наверное надо `url: "/post/signup",`

Comment: пут к файлу ведь, все равно 404

Comment: Проверьте доступен ли файл напрямую, без аякса; потом проверьте куда идёт запрос через инструменты разработчика браузера

Comment: Нет на прямую не доступен прямую 404 тоже, а как сделать доступным?

Comment: вынесите код файла в компонент и обращайтесь к нему через action контроллера - настройка .htaccess для корректной работы с фреймворком перенаправляет все запросы к серверу на index.php в корне сайта

Comment: а какой action контроллера отвечает во view layouts/main.php не знаете?

Comment: @mega94 это [макет](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-views.html#layouts), который является общим для всех страниц, подгружается при любом action, если не переопределён в нём и не используется `renderPartial()`,  `renderAjax()`...